# OTA for Android Things

Tags: android-things

How can I update my Android Things preview 1 with preview 2? Is there an automatic OTA available or isn't this possible right now, so that I have to flash the sdcard (from my Raspberry Pi)?

Comment: Cuurently OTA is not available.You have to download [preview 2](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/download.html) binaries manually  and flash to sdcard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT1:**

Currently, OTA is not available.You have to download preview 2 binaries manually and flash to sdcard.

**EDIT2:(2017 Jun 30)**

Now,OTA is available using  [androidthing console](https://partner.android.com/things/console/).

For OTA automatic updates, you have to create factory image then download it and flash it on your sdcard/board. Thats it, from next time onwards whenever there is OS/security update.Updates will be downloaded and install automatically.Also you can update your applications from console.See below image and for more info [refer](https://developer.android.com/things/console/index.html).

[image: Turn O automatic updates and download build]

Comment: But I thought, that these was the "killer feature" of Android Things. Every time the latest updates. Let's hope, that this will be included into the final release.

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned at IO 2017, OTA updates will be available via the IoT Developer Console. However I believe now because it's in developer preview, these features are not available.

https://iot.google.com/console

> The IoT Developer Console is the best place for developing Android Things or Weave on your devices.

More info in the docs as always: https://developers.google.com/iot/dev-console/

Comment: But the OTA are for the apps and not the OS. We'll have to wait until the function is fully enrolled in the console.

Comment: Does anybody know if i can host my own developer console ? i do not have public internet access for my devices.

Comment: @jah not really a developer console. But you could use adb on your local network to uninstall your app and install new version. If you're refering to update OS from local then I guess the answer is no.